# Making a timer in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm making a Jungle timer program for League of Legends, where I will, when I click a button, start a timer for how long it will take the jungle camp to respawn.

My question is, how do I make such a timer?

Comment: What have you searched for? Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx), like this

```
    ' Create a new DispatcherTimer
    Private _mytimer As New DispatcherTimer 

    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Set interval for timer
        _mytimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000)
        ' Handle tick event
        AddHandler _mytimer.Tick, ...

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Timer_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
        ' Start timer on button click
        _mytimer.Start()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) or perhaps [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx). Create a textbox or whatever for the time span entry. .NET's [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) class has a constructor or static helper method which can parse a string in the form `hh:mm:ss.ss`. When the button is pressed, create the timer using that time span (converting it to milliseconds if needed), and provide the timer a delegate/callback method. The timer will call that method when the time span has elapsed. Put some code in that method to alert you.

Answer (score 1):

From the answer from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9c8397c8-737a-45b7-9a4a-27f9d282e6e2/coundown-timer-in-wpf-with-vb?forum=wpf).

You have to use the `DispatcherTime` class. For that, import the following class at the very beginning of your document.

```vb
Imports System.Windows.Threading
```

Then after the `Class MainWindow`, declare the DispatchTimer with an identifier (`tmr1`):

```vb
Dim tmr1 As New DispatcherTimer
```

Then add this code after the declaration:

```vb
Sub New()
InitializeComponent()
tmr1 .Interval = Timespan.FromSeconds(6) 
AddHandler tmr1.Tick, AddressOf tmr1Tick
tmr1 .Start() 
End Sub 
 
Private Sub tmr1Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
'If errors exist, then type the "Private Sub tmr1Tick...End Sub"
'Enter your code. This code is for when the timer ticks
End Sub
```